# Print if for the same 1st field there's a single value of 2nd field on all lines

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file with two columns separated by one space. The second column will only have either `T` or `F` in it. I want to read the letter in the first column, eg: `A` has 3 lines with the same letter `T` in the second column, then I will keep `A`, however, when has mixed letter in the second column as for `B` and `D`, will be removed.

```
A T
A T
A T
B T
B T
B F
C F
C F
D F
D T
D F
```

I want to print if for the same 1st field there's a single value of 2nd field on all lines.
Expected output:

```
A T
A T
A T
C F
C F
```

I think `awk` may able to do this? Thank you ahead for your help!

Comment: Not alway 3 rows, it is random for rows in each value, and yes they were sorted in consecutive

Comment: Why 5th and 6th lines would not printed? There is 2 B with T?

Comment: Are we allowed to use [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way with `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{if (x[$1]++){if ($2!=t){z[$1]++}} else {t=$2};
next}!($1 in z)' infile infile
```

This process the file twice - 1st pass it checks if there are different values of 2nd field when 1st field is the same value - if so it uses `$1` as an array index then on 2nd pass it prints only if 1st field is not an index of the array.
Or, if you don't mind using `sort` with `awk`:

```
sort -u infile | awk 'NR==FNR{seen[$1]++;next}seen[$1]==1' - infile
```

`sort -u` removes the duplicate lines from the file and pipes the result to `awk` which counts the 1st field occurrences and then processes the whole file again printing the lines if the count is `1`.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -e '
   # this is a do-while loop which collects lines till the time the first
   # field remains the same. We break out of the loop when we see
   # a line whose 1st field != prev lines 1st field **OR** we hit the eof.
  :a
     $bb
     N
  /^\(\S\+\) .\(\n\1 .\)*$/ba

  :b

  # all equal
  # **Action:** Print and quit

  /^\(\S\+ .\)\(\n\1\)*$/q


  # all same 1st fld, but lines unequal, otw would have matched above
  # **Action:** Drop the whole block as its uninteresting

  /^\(\S\+\) .\(\n\1 .\)*$/d


  # all equal, and trailing line part of next line
  # **Action:** Display upto the last newline and restart 
  # with the trailing portion

  /^\(\(\S\+ .\)\(\n\2\)*\)\n[^\n]*$/{
     h
     s//\1/p   
     g
  }


  # of same 1st fld but some lines unequal, and trailing portion has
  # next line
  # **Action:** strip till the last newline, and restart over with the
  # trailing part

  s/.*\(\n\)/\1/
  D
' yourfile
```

This is a very interesting problem for "Sed" to solve. However, what I find lacking is a somewhat better or shall I say larger set of inputs provided by OT on SE. What I propose is that the testcases of realistic magnitude and variety can be placed on the htttp:/pastebin site which is very useful for such things.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/), then you can collapse the data as follows:

```
datamash -W groupby 1 countunique 2 collapse 2 < file 
A   1   T,T,T
B   2   T,T,F
C   1   F,F
D   2   F,T,F
```

That makes it simple to post-process with `awk` for example:

```
datamash -W groupby 1 countunique 2 collapse 2 < file | 
  awk '$2==1 {n = split($3,a,","); for (i=1;i<=n;i++) print $1, a[i]}'
A T
A T
A T
C F
C F
```

Comment: I'd do it like `datamash -t' ' -g1 unique 2 <infile | grep -v , | grep -Ff- infile` (assuming there's no comma in the input values)

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, one more alternative with AWK without the need to double read the file . Seems to work even with unsorted file or even with entries found only once in the file.

```
$ awk '( a[$1] && (($2!=a[$1]) || ($1 in bad)) ) {bad[$1]++}; \
{a[$1]=$2;f1[FNR]=$1;f2[FNR]=$2}; \
END {for (i in f1) {if (!(f1[i] in bad)) print i,f1[i],f2[i]}}' ./tmp/file12


1 A T
2 A T
3 A T
12 C F
13 C F
21 E F
```

In where file12 is like:

```
$ cat -n ./tmp/file12
 1  A T
 2  A T
 3  A T
 4  B T
 5  B T
 6  B F
 7  B F
 8  B T
 9  B F
10  B F
11  B F
12  C F
13  C F
14  D F
15  D T
16  D F
17  D F
18  D F
19  D F
20  D F
21  E F
```

Some explanation:

```
( a[$1] && (($2!=a[$1]) || ($1 in bad)) ) {bad[$1]++};
# The first time value $1 is checked,a[$1] will return null/0 since a[$1]
# has never been assigned. Thus a[$1] will be evaluated as false by
# condition check and further condition check and record bad marking will be skipped.
# The second time (second line) a[$1] will have a value and will be evaluated as true . 
# Then we check if $2 is equal to previous a[$1]=$2. If it is equal all ok.  
# Otherwise if current $2 <> previous a[$1] $2value, mark this record as bad.
# Finally there is a last check if record has been already been marked as bad.

{a[$1]=$2;f1[FNR]=$1;f2[FNR]=$2};     #some array delcaration

END {for (i in f1) {if (!(f1[i] in bad)) print i,f1[i],f2[i]}}' ./tmp/file12 
# Printing the lines of file that does not belong in bad boys.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '
    /\n/D
    :1
    $! {
        N
        /^\(\S\+\s\).*\n\1[^\n]\+$/ b1
    }
    /^\([^\n]\+\n\)\(\1\)\+[^\n]\+$/! D
    h
    s/\n[^\n]\+$//p
    g
    s/.*\n/\n/
    D
    ' file
```

Comment: This fails when a value occurs only once, try adding the line `G F` to OP's input...